# Characterization of Menger property using Menger game

Tags: selection-principles

Hurewicz proved the following result :

The Player ONE does not have a winning strategy in the game $G_{fin}(\mathcal{O},\mathcal{O})$ or Menger game if and only if $X$ satisfies $S_{fin}(\mathcal{O},\mathcal{O})$.

Since the class of open sets is closed under finite intersecions and arbitrary unions. What happens if a class of particular type of subset is closed under arbitrary unions but not closed under finite intersections ?

Does there exist a family $\mathcal{A}$(closed under arbitrary unions) of subsets of a space $X$ for which Player ONE has a winning strategy in the game $G_{fin}(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{A})$ and $X$ satisfies $S_{fin}(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{A})$ ?

Comment: The question is unclear. O denotes the family of open covers of the space, not the family of open subsets of the space. In the Wikipedia entry for "selection principle", there is a result of similar type to that you are asking for, by F. Jordan.